How setup AudioManager setting for Android App to play 2 audio streams using different playback SDK?
I have a usecase where I'd like to playback both a music file locally with ExoPlayer, and a remote stream from LiveKit, https://github.com/livekit.
I am unsure how to set up Audio Manager such that the playback will not affect each other.
I have tried to set following attribute
ContentType to CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC and Usage to USAGE_MEDIA
However, when connecting with LiveKit the locally played audio seems to stop.
Is there an limitation to playing audio from different audio source such as webrtc and mp3?

Do you want to mix the songs simultaneously or Play one after the another by changing the focus?

I'd like to mix the locally played mp3, with a remote voice transmitted over WebRTC via LiveKit SDK.
